# Storing structural break points with "foreach" loop in stata

Tags: loops, time-series, regression, stata, panel-data

```
read.csv("C:\Users\easy\Desktop\workbook.csv")
```

I need to estimate the structural breakpoint of regression over a list of countries in my dataset and I need to store these breakeven points for each country I have and display these breakeven points in a table form once the loop finishes. My dataset is panel data that is why I need to loop over the countries.

I estimate the regression for each country in my `countrynum` variable of countries' list.  And I try to store the breakeven point for each country regression estimation as follows

```
foreach i in  countrynum {
    by countrynum, sort: reg y x1 x2 x3  if `i'== countrynum
    est store `r'(breakdate)
 }
```

Stata is returning the following error message:

```
( invalid name
) invalid name
r(7);
```

Any idea what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the syntax fixes that Nick Cox aptly laid out, what you are missing is `sbsingle` or some other structural break command before asking Stata for `r(breakdate)`; [see here for more](https://www.stata.com/features/overview/structural-breaks/). After that you could do something like this, assuming that your panels are identified by `countrynum`.

```
* EX DATA
webuse usmacro, clear
tempfile append
save `append', replace
append using `append', gen(countrynum)

* Run By program (ssc install runby)
capture program drop panel_breakdate
program panel_breakdate
    tsset date 
    regress fedfunds L.fedfunds
    estat sbsingle
    gen breakdate = r(breakdate)
end
    
runby panel_breakdate, by(countrynum) verbose
* After this format your breakdate how you please.
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot wrong with your code, unfortunately, although you haven't noticed various errors because they are errors of meaning, not errors of syntax.

For a start,

```
foreach i in  countrynum {
```

does **not** trigger a loop over the distinct values of `countrynum`. It is a loop over one item, the variable name `countrynum`.

So your test becomes

```
if countrynum == countrynum
```

which is always true, and the loop is no loop, but equivalent to

```
by countrynum, sort: reg y x1 x2 x3  
est store `r'(breakdate)
```

Now the next problem is that the first command runs through several regressions, but only results for the last regression (for the last country named) will remain in memory.

The error that Stata noticed is that it does not know what you mean by

```
`r'(breakdate)
```

You are, it seems, referring to a result that requires extra syntax to get

```
`r(breakdate)'
```

Positive suggestion. Using `statsby` is a much better idea.

Answer (score 2):

### General Solution

I have a solution to your problem I believe. This program needs to all be run at the same time due to the use of local variables. This worked for me on the usmacro test data where I made half the observations country 1 and the other half country 2. It should work for you as well as long as your data is `tsset` already.

```
levelsof countrynum
foreach lev in `r(levels)' {
    reg y x1 x2 x3 if countrynum == `lev'
    estat sbsingle
    scalar break`lev' = r(breakdate)
}
scalar list
```

As long as you have no scalars previously made, it will return a list of all the breakdates for the countries with the syntax of `(break)(countrynum)` without the parentheses. Let me know if this doesn't work for you, it's difficult without any example data from you but it works in my test environment.

### Example

If you want to see how this works before you run it on your dataset use the following commands at once,

```
clear all
webuse usmacro
gen countrynum = 01 if _n < 35
    replace countrynum = 22 if countrynum == .
tsset date
levelsof countrynum
foreach lev in `r(levels)' {
    reg fedfunds L.fedfunds inflation if countrynum == `lev'
    estat sbsingle
    scalar break`lev' = r(breakdate)
}
scalar list
```

which will return the following in the stata output,

```
. scalar list
    break22 = 1980q4
    break1 = 1958q1
```

Comment: The idea is good, but you need an `if` qualifier on the regression to avoid getting the same result again and again.

Comment: As the original author of `levelsof` I regard its frequent use where `statsby` is simpler with mixed feelings!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I've gone ahead and made the edit required. Don't worry Nick, I'm a huge fan of `levelsof`.

Comment: Thanks, Jesse and Nick for your help. Jesse, I tried your code, it works but repeats the estimation 3 times ( equals to the numbers of levels). Also, I was trying to post my dataset for illustration but I did not know how (apologies I am still new to this). Any help on how to upload a dataset so that my problem would be clearer to you? Many thanks

Comment: Interesting! In your example your panel has no overlap in date, so if you were to extend to a balanced panel you'll get a repeated time value error in your  `tsset date`.

Comment: Thats a good point. If you have a balanced panel it might make more sense to use Nick's answer to look more into the statsby package. @samahhajjar you can open a .csv of the data in a text editor and then copy and paste to [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com).

Comment: thanks @JesseKaczmarski, I have uploaded my dataset. When running your code it it's repeating the estimation 3 times however with the entire sample and not for separate countries.

Comment: @samahhajjar can you include a link to the pastebin so that I can download it and try it? It shouldn't do that but I'll definitely take a look

Comment: As a side note, your error sounds like you're leaving out `if countrynum == \`lev'` that comes after the regression command.

Comment: @JesseKaczmarski yes it is true I missed that part. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @samahhajjar I'm glad it worked out! Make sure to mark my response as the answer if it worked for you.